# Is it possible to create a foreign key reference on a cross DB?

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [foreign keys on table from different database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424327/foreign-keys-on-table-from-different-database)

I just wanted to know whether there is any way of creating a foreign key reference on a column on a database table to another column of a different database table (Cross DB)

Comment: Have a look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1429473/971693

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4452132/44522 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/265921/44522

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot implement a foreign key across databases.

You could use a trigger to enforce a constraint, but be aware that triggers can be disabled and there are also scenarios where they won't fire.